# Register a Windows Explorer Shell Extension in HKCU

Tags: windows, com, explorer, shell-extensions

Is it possible to register a shell extension just in the user registy hive?

The COM classes should be fine, but will Explorer load those also from `HKCU` ?

Eg.: a `IContextMenu` implementing a context menu handler.

Comment: What kind of extension?

Comment: Explorer uses COM as a standard client, so yes. More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724498.aspx

Comment: @SimonMourier, Yes for the COM server, no question. But will explorer execute the extension (this is the question).

Comment: Yes, if it falls in the merged views of HKCR (follow my link)

Comment: Shell will load your IContextMenu extension registered in HKCU.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Explorer (and shell views in other applications) will load shell extensions from HKCU. One exception is that UAC elevated processes will not load extensions from HKCU because of security/spoofing issues.

Comment: Official link here: "Application Compatibility: UAC: COM Per-User Configuration" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb756926(v=msdn.10)